# Using different css and removing items for mobile view of django_admin

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I want to remove specific items from my Django admin when it's viewed on a mobile device as shown below. Also, when I open my web app on a mobile device I want it to be viewed a little bit different so I want a different css to be loaded. Is there a way of doing that? [What I want to remove and what to leave on a mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXr8Z.png)

For example I'm adding items like that:

```
admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
admin.site.register(Schedule, ScheduleAdmin)
admin.site.register(PaymentAhead, PaymentAheadAdmin)
```

I'm sorry if the question is super obvious and generic, but this is my first ever Django app and I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with Django, but a CSS option would be to get the user-agent and if its mobile set ``visibility:hidden;``. You could do this by media queries on screen size too if its a positioning issue.

Comment: Can't get the element to hide, unfortunately like this...

Comment: Any specific reason why not? May be able to offer other recommendations.

Comment: Because I'm rendering the html like this                `  {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
                {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<a class="navbar-brand">{% render_with_template_if_exist title|lower|add:"/admin_app_name.html" title %}</a>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
                {% block object-tools %}{% endblock %} `